# Put colorbar on specific hist2d in a subplot of hist and hist2d

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, subplot, colorbar

I have seen a few suggestions of using ImageGrid (like over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61062216/adding-one-colorbar-for-hist2d-subplots-and-make-them-adjacent)) but my issue is that these are all hist2d without different kinds of plots as well.
Maybe the solution is obvious to some but I am not sure how to specifically show the color map of a hist2d in a specific ax when not all of my other subplots are hist2d.

Here is an example of my what I am trying to do, with randomly generated data. The titles and such are there based on my actual data, but for the purposes of this demo you can just ignore those.

Here's the sample code:

```
# imports
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

# seed random number
np.random.seed(0)

# random normally distributed data
entries = 100000
# first signal
mu1, sigma1 = 0.5, 0.01 # mean and standard deviation
s1 = np.random.normal(mu1, sigma1, entries)
# second signal
mu2, sigma2 = 0.45, 0.02 # mean and standard deviation
s2 = np.random.normal(mu2, sigma2, entries)

# fig and ax
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 3, figsize = (30, 15))

# fill plots
ax[0, 0].hist(s1, bins = 100, density = True, range = (0.45, 0.55))
# log scale for z axis
ax[0, 1].hist2d(s2, s1, bins = 100, range = ((0.35, 0.55), (0.45, 0.55)), norm = mpl.colors.LogNorm(), cmap = "plasma")
ax[0, 2].hist(s2, bins = 100, density = True, range = (0.35, 0.55))

ax[1, 0].hist(s1, bins = 100, density=True, range = (0.45, 0.55))
# log scale for z axis
ax[1, 1].hist2d(s2, s1, bins = 100, range = ((0.35, 0.55), (0.45, 0.55)), norm = mpl.colors.LogNorm(), cmap = "plasma")
ax[1, 2].hist(s2, bins = 100, density = True, range = (0.35, 0.55))

# plot settings (titles, etc)
for i in range(0,2):
    for j in range(0,3):
        if i == 0:
            ax[i, j].set_title(r"proton in FD", fontsize = 22)
        elif i == 1:
            ax[i, j].set_title(r"proton in CD", fontsize = 22)
        ax[i, j].grid(color = 'black', linestyle = ':', linewidth = 0.5, zorder = 0)
        ax[i, j].ticklabel_format(axis = "y", style = "sci", scilimits = (0,0))

        # axis names
        if j == 0:
            ax[i, j].set(xlabel = "MM$^2$ [GeV$^2$]")
            ax[i, j].set(ylabel = "Count")
        if j == 1:
            ax[i, j].set(xlabel = "IM($2\gamma$) [GeV]")
            ax[i, j].set(ylabel = "MM$^2$ [GeV$^2$]")
        if j == 2:
            ax[i, j].set(xlabel = "IM($2\gamma$) [GeV]")
            ax[i, j].set(ylabel = "Count")

fig.suptitle("final states: full data skim $ep\gamma$ + any additional particles", fontsize=25)
plt.show()
```

And here is the output I get of the above code:

[image]

What I would like to be able to do is put the colorbar for the two hist2d images, but when I try to do something like ax[0,1].colorbar() I get the issue that ax doesn't have colorbar. I would have to use fig.colorbar() or plt.colorbar() and I am not sure how to use that to show for a specific subplot.

Is there a way to do this? Thank you for the help.

Comment: @JohanC Unfortunately this does not work for me. I get the following error: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get_array'

Comment: Yes, I see. `hist2d()` returns 4 values, and you need the last. So, `_, _, _, h1 = ax[0, 1].hist2d(s2, s1, ...)` and then `fig.colorbar(h1, ax=ax[0,1]) `.

Comment: @JohanC wow! that works! Thank you so much. Would you mind leaving this as a comment so that I may up vote you answer?